# LinearLayout with rounded corners and background color

Tags: java, android, android-layout

CompileSdkVersion 26, if it's important. I want to create LinearLayout with rounded corners, and background color.

I created 2 LinearLayouts, one with corners, and one with color, but their shapes do not match my expectations.

Code from activity

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/whitegrey"
            android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

custom_border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <padding android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp" android:top="8dp" android:bottom="8dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#444444" />
    </shape>
```

Actually, there is rounded border, and behind, there is rectangular layout with target color. I want to fill with target color only what is inside borders.
Is there any way to set the fill color, preferably in custom_border.xml?

Here, what I have at the moment:
[image: Here, what I have at the moment]

Here, what I want to achieve:
[image: Here, what I want to achieve]

View from phone, the letters on the left are cut off:
[image: View from phone, the letters on the left are cut off]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code samples you provide us, it doesn't seem necessary to me to have two LinearLayout. Only the layout with `android:background="@drawable/custom_border"` is required.

To achieve the expected result, just add the property `<solid android:color="@color/whitegrey" />` to your `custom_border.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp" android:top="8dp" android:bottom="8dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#444444" />
    <solid android:color="@color/whitegrey" />
</shape>
```

I wish I was able to help you!